# How to say "layout" in Russian (in a web design context)

Tags: перевод, одним-словом, узус, информатика

I'm a web designer.  Right now, I'm working for a Russian client and I have to tell him that I'm going to be working on the **layout** of his site. The translator gives lots of options, and don't know which is better in this context.

What word do you suggest I use to translate **layout** in a web design or graphic design context?

Comment: Noticed today that MS Word uses word "Макет" to translate (Table) Layout.

Comment: Also, keyboard layout = раскладка

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My suggestions:

- (web)site layout — макет сайта, оформление сайта
- (web)page layout — макет страницы, разметка страницы
- graphic design layout — макет, графический макет, макет изображения.

Comment: Spasibo bolshoe Eugene!
If i have to choose one for website layout, which can be better: макет сайта or оформление сайта ?

Comment: макет сайта is temporary, unfinished work, preview. оформление сайта - more like 'design', 'look'.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you're actually talking about "вёрстка". If you mean the very process of translating psd-files (or whatever is drawn) to html, this is exactly the word you're looking for.

The coder who usually deals with such translations is called a "верстальщик".

Comment: Thank you for the information. 
Was more about making the layout of the website, in the meaning that the client can see the structure and the main aesthetic idea of the site.
Thank you anyway!

Comment: "Верстка" - это процесс написания markup, а не layout.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a software developer who worked a lot with HTML and CSS in the 2000's.  I can say that Russian has adopted a lot of IT terms from English without modification.

*Верстка* isn't a good translation because it refers to complete HTML and CSS with pixel accuracy, whereas *layout* refers to general outlines.  *Макет* is okay.  But you can simply just say "layout" — this word was borrowed as is.